# Return a list of vowels in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm having a small issue in Erlang. I want to return a list of all the vowels of a string. For example:

```
vowels:conditional("AGGEHA").
["A","E","A"]
```

Here is the code proposed:

```
-module(vowels).
-compile([export_all]).

isvowel('') -> false;
isvowel(C) -> if
                  C =:= "A" -> true;
                  C =:= "E" -> true;
                  C =:= "I" -> true;
                  C =:= "O" -> true;
                  C =:= "U" -> true;
                  true -> false
              end.

conditional([]) -> [];
conditional([A|T]) -> case isvowel(A) of
                          true -> [A] ++ conditional(T);
                          false -> [1] ++ conditional(T)
                      end.
```

The problem is when I use the `conditional` function, it always return `false` (or in this case, a list of 1 depending on the length of the string (I used this as a debugger)). Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: why not using standart module? For example, so : http://ideone.com/Zexca2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing `''`, `""` and `$` syntax. The minimal fix is:

```
is_vowel(C) ->
  if C =:= $A -> true;
  ...
  true -> false
  end.
```

A much better solution is direct pattern matching and a list comprehension with a filter:

```
is_vowel($A) -> true;
...
is_vowel(_) -> false.

conditional(String) -> [C || C <- String, is_vowel(C)].
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I never remember the '' or "" syntax!

Answer (score 8):

You can use either the standard [`lists:filter/2` function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#filter-2) or a list comprehension for this, along with using the [`lists:member/2` function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#member-2) for determining whether a character is a vowel or not:

```
conditional(String) ->
    lists:filter(fun(C) -> lists:member(C, [$A,$E,$I,$O,$U]) end, String).
```

or

```
conditional(String) ->
    [C || C <- String, lists:member(C, [$A,$E,$I,$O,$U])].
```

Given your example input `"AGGEHA"` both of these return the list of characters `"AEA"`, but if you really want them to return each vowel as a string `["A","E","A"]` like you've shown, it's easiest to do that with the list comprehension by just placing the returned character in a list:

```
conditional(String) ->
    [[C] || C <- String, lists:member(C, [$A,$E,$I,$O,$U])].
```

With that change, you'll get the original result you requested:

```
1> vowels:conditional("AGGEHA").
["A","E","A"]
```